# Ubuntu on ASUS motherboard. Any compatibility issue?

Tags: asus, compatibility, motherboard

I need your help! I am building my first pc.

Can I install the latest Ubuntu (or older versions) on ASUS TUF Gaming X570-PLUS motherboard with AMD Ryzen 9 3900X? I tried to search online for the compatibility of ASUS TUF Gaming X570 with Ubuntu, but didn't find anything useful. There is a list of linux compatibility report: https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report-201810.pdf. However, it doesn't have any information on TUF X570.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, any of amd64 architecture should run on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What about the motherboard? Does it have any compatibility issues with Ubuntu? Win10 is the only official os of TUF X570 listed on ASUS website. This question might seem silly, but I have zero experience in building a pc by myself before. So please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't work, then return the motherboard. It's very likely to work.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014   (but ensure you've downloaded the ISO perfectly https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then written to media flawlessly (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD is any media used inc. thumb-drives))

Comment: It should work. Maybe try Fedora or OpenSUSE instead, just in case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone's help!!! I think I will try to install it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the same 'board but close enough.

"TUF GAMING X570-PLUS (WI-FI), Ubuntu 18.10" Page 11 of 13:

Asus Linux-Status-report_201904.pdf
https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report_201904.pdf

Note: Check any Linux Status Report For ASUS Desktop Motherboard.pdf's URL for its release date.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I guess the Wi-Fi and non Wi-Fi versions are essentially the same.