# Motherboard compatibilty with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, asus, compatibility, motherboard

I am planning to buy a new computer that comes with an ASUS TUF GAMING B460-PLUS motherboard, but I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on it instead of Windows. How can I find out whether this motherboard is compatible with Ubuntu?

I have searched [this list](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report-201810.pdf) from [Ubuntu on ASUS motherboard. Any compatibility issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216013/ubuntu-on-asus-motherboard-any-compatibility-issue), but it is not listed there. If it is not on that list does that mean it is not compatible with Ubuntu? Is there another way to find out if this motherboard is compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: If there is no information available regarding Ubuntu/Linux compatibility for you mainboard, I would suggest looking at the individual components (chipset, networking, etc) if they are supported instead.

Comment: Advice: Purchase from a vendor with a generous return policy. You can do a lot of research, yet still be surprised when it's in your hands.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because hardware recommendations are off topic on AU and should he asked [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Somewhat newer model, should be very similar. Asus tuf gaming x570-plus
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445883

Comment: @24601 Hardware recommendation questions are off topic at Ask Ubuntu, however this is not a hardware recommendation question. It's an on topic hardware compatibility. question. Hardware  compatibility questions are on topic at Ask Ubuntu. I edited the tags of this question to make this more clear. Please retract your close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Linux Status Report for ASUS Desktop Motherboards](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report-201810.pdf) the ASUS TUF *B450M*-PLUS GAMING motherboard is tested as compatible with Ubuntu 18.04, so it seems very likely that the similar ASUS TUF *B460M*-PLUS GAMING motherboard model would also be compatible with Ubuntu 20.04. In order to get a more focused evaluation of the motherboard's compatibility before you install Ubuntu, boot from the Ubuntu installer live USB and run Ubuntu as a live session.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS B450M-A/CSM which was promised to be ubuntu-compatible by the vendor. However, I've had problems with the board locking up during the warmer half of the year, and during summers, I have to turn off that desktop and use my laptop instead.

I found out that the CPU fan control chip (IT8655E) isn't supported. I'm using https://github.com/a1wong/it87 (a custom version of it87.ko), which was modified to support it, but I'm guessing that the control loop (cpu temp <-> fan speed) isn't working correctly. I asked Asus for a copy of the programmer's guide for the chip, but they told me they wouldn't provide it.

I don't know if the same problem affects the B460M.